# Problem with persistence

Tags: java, orm, persistence, jpa-2.0

I'm using `EclipseLink` in my `J2SE` project. I'm using `mysql` and JPA. I have a simple entity with primary key and `String` field. I can read from database using `EntityManager#createQuery` but when I try to `persist` or `merge` entity nothing is put in database and no exception are thrown. I can insert data manually without problems (using same credentials as in `persistence.xml` file). Please help! The problem isn't related to jpa implementation I guess because changing provider in `persistence.xml` to `Hibernate` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the `persist()` or `merge()` inside an active transaction. Then you need to call the `commit()` method on the transaction object.

Create a transaction by calling `getTransaction()` on the `EntityManager` instance, getting back an EntityTransaction object and then calling `begin()` on it. Call `commit()` on it after your entity updates (such as `merge()`) are done.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html